# Long time execution action asp.net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-core

What is the best approach to write an action that takes 1 minute or more to execute but returns immediately the control to the view ?

I know that there is Hangfire solution, but it uses a database to store executions and I need something more simple.

I´m using asp.net core.

This is what my action is doing:

```
    private void CipherData()
    {
        var posts = _context.Posts.All().ToList();
        foreach (var post in posts)
        {
            post.TextCrypt = EncryptionHelper.Encrypt(post.Text);
            _context.Posts.Update(post);
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: There are plenty of questions similar to this one, not sure if they are also about asp.net core but this is a generic problem so I doubt there are too many differences that one of these would not work: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net+fire+forget

Comment: Wouldn't that be better offloaded on a process that is more resilient than a fire-forget task (or something of the sort)? Seems you would want to know if it did/didn't finish.

Comment: I really don´t want to know if it finishes or not.

Answer (score -1):

I was having problem using Task.Run (that is a way to do this), because it loses the database context (injected).

So I create a new database context to use in this process. Basically:

```
public IActionResult CipherData()
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
       //create a new dbcontext here   
       //perform database manipulation using this new dbcontext
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Comment: Bad idea. IIS can drop your task any time.